# $\ell_o$ Minimization (Minimizing the support of a vector)

Tags: linear-programming, sparse-matrices, compressed-sensing, integer-programming

I have been looking into the problem
$\min: \|x \|_0$ subject to$: Ax=b$. $\|x \|_0$ is not a linear function and can't be solved as a linear (or integer) program in its current form. Most of my time has been spent looking for a representation different from the one above (formed as a linear/integer program). I know there are approximation methods (Basis Pursuit, Matching Pursuit, the $\ell_1$ problem), but I haven't found an exact formulation in any of my searching and sparse representation literature. I have developed a formulation for the problem, but I would love to compare with anything else that is available. Does anyone know of such a formulation?

Thanks in advance,
Clark

P.S.
I'm aware that the $\|x\|_0$ problem is NP-hard, and as such, probably will not yield an exact formulation as an LP (unless P=NP). I was more referring to an exact formulation or an LP relaxation.

Comment: I am confused: Do you look for an exact reformulation or an LP relaxation?

Comment: An exact formulation is my major goal, but I would be interested to see a relaxation as well.

Comment: Still a question remains: What is the aim of your reformulation? In other words: what is wrong with the $\ell^0$-minimization problem? As you have written: The problem is NP-hard and hence, there will be no "easy" reformulation with out any further assumption on $A$ (unless $P=NP$).

Comment: The goal of any reformulation that would be interesting to me would include a linear objective function. While the problem is NP-hard, the reformulation could be susceptible to various heuristics or other approximations.

I know any formulation will not be an "easy" one, but I still wanted to see if any existed.

Comment: Sorry, what do you denote by $\|\dot\|_0$?

Comment: It is the number of non-zero elements in the vector. The support of a vector $s=supp(x)$ is a vector $x$ whose zero elements have been removed. The size of the support $|s| = \|x\|_0$ is the number of elements in the vector $s$.

Comment: You can trivially cast it as an integer programming problem by introducing an indicator vector $z$, so that $z^T1$ gives you the $\ell_0$-quasi-norm of $x$, and then recast in terms of $z$. The problem remains hard, but now the objective is linear.

Comment: Thanks Suvrit. That is actually similar to the formulation I have been looking using. I was hoping that someone had some published work on it, but perhaps not.

Answer (score 1):

You can formulate this as an integer program.  Let z be a vector of binary variables, and let Uj be upper bounds on the x variables.   Hopefully you can derive some reasonably tight lower bounds based on the constraints Ax = b, but if not, use a suitably large value for each Uj.    Then the following MIP will give you the minimal support that satisfies Ax = b:

min e'z                          // e is a vector of all ones
Ax = b
xj = Uj*zj <= 0
x >= 0, 0 <= z <= 1, z binary.

Note that I assumed x >= 0 here.   If some or all of the x variables have lower bounds below 0, you can introduce nonnegative variables u and v, then let x = u - v do the some
MIP formulation for the constraints Au - Av = b, adding a binary for each u and v variable.